# Given $5$ points on a sphere, divide the surface into $5$ congruent connected regions containing one point.

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, combinatorial-geometry

There are $5$ points on the surface of a sphere. Is it always possible to divide the surface into $5$ connected congruent regions such that each region contains one of the $5$ points?

Comment: Sure. Pick an axis along which all of the points have distinct projections, then define the regions to look something like [this](http://www.wikiart.org/en/m-c-escher/sphere-spirals).

Comment: @Rahul: Is it clear that each region will contain (exactly) one of the 5 points?